# close a collapse panel(accordion) from other control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to close and disable the accordion from a click event of a label.

When clicking the label. the accordion should be disabled and closed. I can make it disabled by using `addClass` method

```
$('#c5').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

```html
<div class="accordionHeader">
    <h3 id="c5">Advance Settings (C5)</h3>
    <div class="accordionContent">my content</div>
</div>
```

For closing the accordion I tried using

```
$('#c5').prop('active',false);
$('#c5').attr('active',false);
```

neither one works.

I do not want to use before I have to call this from other control

```
$(".accordionHeader").accordion({
    header: "h3",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-collapsible):

> Setting `active` to `false` will collapse all panels. This requires the `collapsible` option to be `true`.

So, using the following HTML,

```
<div class="accordionHeader">
     <h3 id="c5">Advance Settings (C5)</h3>
     <div class="accordionContent">my content</div>
</div>
<label id='c5label'>Disable accordion <input type="checkbox" /></label>
```

this JS will start the accordion and close/disable on the first click on the label `#c5label':

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".accordionHeader").accordion({ collapsible: true });
    $('#c5label').click(function(){
        if( $( ".accordionHeader" ).accordion( "option", "active") === false )
            return;

        $('#c5').addClass('ui-state-disabled');
        $( ".accordionHeader" ).accordion( "option", "active", false );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: hi i tried urs and it works.
however i got quite a few of accordion using accordionheader class.
if i use ur method. all other accordion will be close as well.
or i should give a id to current accordion?

Comment: i change to  $("#c5accord").accordion("option", "active", false);
i add a id to my accordionheader and it works. i can up u as it say required 15 reputation.
still thanks for the code.